# How to add placeholder to CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/35/)

I am using CKEditor from CDN.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
```

As per the instructions [here](http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/7653/_samples/placeholder.html),
JS:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description',
{
    extraPlugins : 'placeholder'
});
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught The editor instance "description" is already attached to the provided element.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have two `CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' )` statements. Remove the first one.

Comment: I tried without it, but got 2 errors. It is unable to find the placeholder plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/36/

Comment: It's not a standard plugin so you need to download the plugin and install it.

Comment: And besides that, it seems that the "placeholder" functionality that you want isn't really the "placeholder" plugin.

Comment: @LeeTaylor add answer?

Comment: @RahulDesai What are you expecting the placeholder plugin to do for you?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Just to set a placeholder. Nothing else. Can you tell me how do I install the placeholder script inside the CKEditor?

Comment: @RahulDesai "Placeholder" has a variety of meanings. Which one are you talking about?!

Comment: @LeeTaylor I just want to set the text as `Description` in the editor. This text needs to be overwritten when the user starts typing.

Comment: OK, well in that case you won't be needing the placeholder plugin as that is something totally different. As such this question appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153018/how-to-display-the-placeholder-attribute-in-html5-textarea-when-ckeditor-is-acti

Comment: I am not sure where exactly to put the code mentioned here http://alfonsoml.blogspot.in/2012/02/configuration-helper-for-ckeditor.html An example would have been better.

Comment: @RahulDesai did you put the placeholder in ckeditor.. i have similar issue. and can't find the answer